# GCP Speech to Text and Voice activation Detection working together

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, stream, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I feel I am pretty close to getting what I want, but missing a special something. I am wanting to use Google's Speech to Text engine, to live stream audio data (in this case from a wav file, but could be stdin) and generate the transcripts as the app detects silence. I started [with this code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/speech/livecaption_from_file/livecaption_from_file.go) which is *fine* but as much as it says it streams the audio, I only get the trancript back once its finished sending GCP the entire audio file.

My plan: [to use a VAD](http://%22github.com/maxhawkins/go-webrtcvad%22%20%09%22io%22%20%20%09//%22io%22%20%09%22log%22%20)%20%20//%20DURATION%20is%20a%20sweetener%20so%20that%20it%20is%20obvious%20what%20this%20control%20message%20is%20in%20response%20to%20type%20DURATION%20int%20%20//%20ControlMessage%20is%20a%20VAD%20type%20control%20message%20type%20ControlMessage%20struct%20%7B%20%09Code%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DURATION%20%09data%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%20%7D%20%20//%20The%20enumeratable%20types%20of%20DURATION%20const%20(%20%09SILENCE%20DURATION%20=%20iota%20%09PAUSE%20)%20//%20The%20human%20readable%20output%20for%20a%20control%20message%20var%20ops%20=%20map[DURATION]ControlMessage%7B%20%09SILENCE:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ControlMessage%7BSILENCE,%20%22Silence%22%7D,%20%09PAUSE:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ControlMessage%7BPAUSE,%20%22Pause%22%7D,%20%7D%20%20//%20String%20will%20extract%20the%20human%20readable%20type%20for%20a%20control%20message%20func%20(e%20DURATION)%20String()%20string%20%7B%20%09if%20op,%20found%20:=%20ops[e];%20found%20%7B%20%09%09return%20op.data%20%09%7D%20%09return%20%22???%22%20%7D%20%20//%20VadProcessor%20is%20responsible%20for%20configuring%20a%20VAD%20for%20a%20conversation%20type%20VadProcessor%20struct%20%7B%20%09*webrtcvad.VAD%20%09ActiveAudio%20*bytes.Buffer%20%09framesize%20int%20%09sampleRateHertz%20int%20%09sample10msSize%20int%20%09silenceTimeout%20int%20//a%20silence%20is%20the%20smallest%20unit%20of%20nothing%20detected%20%09pauseTimeout%20int%20//a%20pause%20is%20a%20unit%20of%20nothing%20detected,%20made%20up%20of%20silences%20%09currentSilence%20int%20%09currentPause%20int%20%7D%20%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20PreProcess(rawAudio%20chan%20[]byte,%20someBytes%20[]byte)%20%7B%20%20%09frame%20:=%20make([]byte,%20v.framesize)%20%09r%20:=%20bytes.NewBuffer(someBytes)%20%20%09for%20%7B%20%09%09n,%20err%20:=%20io.ReadFull(r,%20frame)%20%09%09if%20err%20==%20io.EOF%20%7C%7C%20err%20==%20io.ErrUnexpectedEOF%20%7B%20%09%09%09//fmt.Println(%22detected%20EOF%22,%20err)%20%09%09%09break%20%09%09%7D%20%09%09if%20err%20!=%20nil%20%7B%20%09%09%09log.Fatal(%22error%20here%20%22,%20err)%20%09%09%09break%20%09%09%7D%20%20%09%09if%20n%20%3E%200%20%7B%20%09%09%09rawAudio%20%3C-%20frame%20%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%20%09%09%09break%20%09%09%7D%20%20%09%7D%20%7D%20%20func%20NewVAD(sampleRateHertz,%20sample10msSize,%20mode%20int)%20(VadProcessor,%20error)%20%7B%20%09tmpVadProcessor,%20err%20:=%20webrtcvad.New()%20%09if%20err%20!=%20nil%20%7B%20%09%09return%20VadProcessor%7B%7D,%20err%20%09%7D%20%09var%20vProcessor%20VadProcessor%20%09vProcessor.VAD%20=%20tmpVadProcessor%20%09//%208kHz%20%09//%20XkHz%20=%3E%20(X%20*%2010)%20*%202%20%09//const%20sample10msSize%20=%20160%20%09vProcessor.framesize%20=%20160%20%09vProcessor.sample10msSize%20=%20sample10msSize%20%09vProcessor.sampleRateHertz%20=%20sampleRateHertz%20%09vProcessor.silenceTimeout%20=%20500%20//definition%20of%20a%20silence%20%09vProcessor.pauseTimeout%20=%203000%20//length%20of%20silence%20before%20moving%20on%20%09vProcessor.currentSilence%20=%200%20//length%20of%20current%20silence%20%09vProcessor.currentPause%20=%200%20//ms%20until%20the%20next%20question%20%09vProcessor.ActiveAudio%20=%20new(bytes.Buffer)%20%20%09//%20set%20its%20aggressiveness%20mode,%20which%20is%20an%20integer%20between%200%20and%203%20%09if%20err%20:=%20vProcessor.VAD.SetMode(mode);%20err%20!=%20nil%20%7B%20//agression%20cuts%20out%20background%20noise...%20%09%09return%20VadProcessor%7B%7D,%20err%20%09%7D%20%20%09if%20ok%20:=%20vProcessor.VAD.ValidRateAndFrameLength(sampleRateHertz,%20sample10msSize);%20!ok%20%7B%20%09%09return%20VadProcessor%7B%7D,%20errors.New(%22invalid%20rate%20or%20frame%20length%22)%20%09%7D%20%20%09return%20vProcessor,%20nil%20%7D%20%20//%20Worker%20is%20responsible%20for%20the%20Voice%20Activity%20Detection,%20taking%20an%20input%20byte%20array%20and%20//%20%20returning%20an%20integer%20representing%20the%20duration%20of%20the%20silence.%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20Worker(rawAudio%20chan%20[]byte,%20vadControl%20chan%20DURATION)%20%7B%20%20%09fmt.Println(%22VAD%20working....%22)%20%09//var%20voiceSize%20int%20//seems%20to%20just%20track%20the%20total%20speaking%20time%20since%20last%20silence,%20leave%20for%20now.%20%09//%20run%20init%20to%20not%20get%20index%20not%20found%20%09v.restartSilence()%20%20%09for%20%7B%20%09%09select%20%7B%20%09%09//we%20need%20a%20context%20to%20cancel%20if%20necesssary%20%09%09//case%20%3C-manager.Canceled():%20%09%09//%09return%20%09%09%09case%20frame%20:=%20%3C-rawAudio:%20%09%09%09%09frameMs%20:=%20len(frame)%20%09%09%09%09if%20frameMs%20!=%20v.sample10msSize%20%7B%20%09%09%09%09%09log.Printf(%22vad:%20invalid%20frame%20size%20(%25v)%20(%25v)%20%5Cn%22,%20frameMs,%20v.sample10msSize)%20%09%09%09%09%09continue%20%09%09%09%09%7D%20%20%09%09%09%09frameActive,%20err%20:=%20v.VAD.Process(v.sampleRateHertz,%20frame)%20%09%09%09%09if%20err%20!=%20nil%20%7B%20%09%09%09%09%09log.Printf(%22vad%20Process%20error:%20(%25v)%20%5Cn%22,%20err)%20%09%09%09%09%09continue%20%09%09%09%09%7D%20%09%09%09%09if%20frameActive%20%7B%20%09%09%09%09%09v.ActiveAudio.Write(frame)%20%09%09%09%09%7D%20%09%09%09%09v.saveResults(frameActive,%20frameMs)%20%09%09%09%09v.sendAndResetSilence(frameActive,%20vadControl)%20%09%09%7D%20%09%7D%20%7D%20%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20saveResults(frameActive%20bool,%20frameMs%20int)%20%7B%20%20%09//%20save%20size%20of%20silence%20and%20voice%20%09if%20frameActive%20%7B%20%09%09//restart%20silenceSize%20%09%09v.restartSilence()%20%09%7D%20else%20%7B%20%09%09//%20there%20is%20no%20voice%20in%20this%20sample%20%09%09v.saveSilenceResult(frameMs)%20%09%7D%20%7D%20%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20sendAndResetSilence(frameActive%20bool,%20vadControl%20chan%20DURATION)%20%7B%20%20%09//its%20just%20a%20check%20to%20see%20if%20the%20state%20has%20changed%20(i%20think)%20-%20not%20foolproof%20%09if%20frameActive%20%7B%20%09%09//vadControl%20%3C-%200%20%09%09return%20%09%7D%20%09if%20v.currentSilence%20==%20v.silenceTimeout*16%20%7B%20%09%09v.currentSilence%20=%200%20%09%09vadControl%20%3C-%20SILENCE%20%09%7D%20%09if%20v.currentPause%20==%20v.pauseTimeout*16%20%7B%20%09%09v.currentPause%20=%200%20%09%09vadControl%20%3C-%20PAUSE%20%09%7D%20%7D%20%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20saveSilenceResult(frameMs%20int)%20%7B%20%20%09v.currentSilence%20%20=%20frameMs%20%09v.currentPause%20%20=%20frameMs%20%7D%20%20func%20(v%20*VadProcessor)%20restartSilence()%20%7B%20%20%09v.currentSilence%20=%200%20%09v.currentPause%20=%200%20%7D) so that I can detect silence, or atleast no voice activity. My VAD is setup to send a message when either 0.5s or 3s of silence are detected. When 3s are detected, I want to consider all data since the last silence as "a phrase". Then send this to GCP and it send back the transript for that.

So far, I have got it succesfully detecting the silences - i.e the implementation of the VAD works, *and* I've got the STT to generate the transcript for the whole audio file, however what I am struggling to do is chop the data up after and when silence is detected, and get GCP to generate the transcript for that bit. I think, in a sentence, I'm struggling with my buffers....

Any help massively appreciated.

On a side note I *think* this is the approach because of the way the GCP STT is implemented, however this may not be best approach, I think `EOF` will close the stream to STT and in that case I would need to create a new one when the VAD detects voice again and call it again. I [decided to make a gist of my code as it would be quite large here](https://gist.github.com/amlwwalker/cb8d07d50e47239b6189e34927f356c5).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the built-in feature to [detect silence](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming-requests) single_utterance
request should automatically end after speech is no longer detected
(defaults to false)